# How to auto list conflicts files in vscode commits message

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In Vscode, when merge conflicts do not list out conflicted files as follow:

I want to list down conflicted files in commits message without have to type manually

```
Merge branch 'xxx/home' of https://git2.xxx.com/xxx/xxxxxxx into xxx/dev

# Conflicts:                         <--- I want to show these
# app/navigators/file000.tsx
# app/theme/file001.ts
```